Django with Signoz opentelemetry Tracing issue
Trying to setup SigNoz with Django for application performance monitoring, so that I can check API calls and DB queries, but I have hit a dead end and now I cannot proceed further, so I request you to help me out with this case.
SigNoz Steps
Requirements
Python 3.8 or newer
for Django, you must define DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE correctly. If your project is called mysite, something like following should work:

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
 

Step 1 : Add OpenTelemetry dependencies
In your requirements.txt file, add these two OpenTelemetry dependencies:


opentelemetry-distro==0.43b0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp==1.22.0
 

Step 2 : Dockerize your application
Update your dockerfile along with OpenTelemetry instructions as shown below:


...

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
# And install OpenTelemetry packages
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

RUN opentelemetry-bootstrap --action=install

# (Optional) Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container (You can choose your own port for this)
EXPOSE 5000

# Set environment variables for OpenTelemetry
ENV OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=<SERVICE_NAME>
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=https://ingest.{REGION}.signoz.cloud:443
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS=signoz-access-token=<SIGNOZ_TOKEN>
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=grpc

# Run app.py with OpenTelemetry instrumentation when the container launches
CMD ["opentelemetry-instrument", "<your_run_command>"]
...
<your_run_command> can be python3 app.py or python manage.py runserver --noreload

After following the above steps I've setup my django project accordingly, I've shared the my project changes below.
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=shopify_sync.settings

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    postgresql-client \
    build-essential \
    libssl-dev \
    net-tools \
    --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt


RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN opentelemetry-bootstrap --action=install

# RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

# (Optional) Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container (You can choose your own port for this)
EXPOSE 5000

# Set environment variables for OpenTelemetry
ENV OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=shopify_sync
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=<SIGNOZ_URL>
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS=signoz-access-token=<SIGNOZ_TOKEN>
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=grpc

RUN mkdir -p /app/code/wapp_dump

COPY . /app/code

COPY catalog.csv /app/code/catalog.csv

WORKDIR /app/code

entrypoint.sh
#! /bin/bash

set -e

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=shopify_sync.settings

opentelemetry-instrument gunicorn shopify_sync.wsgi --workers=5 --log-level=info -k eventlet -b 0.0.0.0:7050 --reload

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: apiserver
    hostname: apiserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerify/app/Dockerfile
    image: shopify-sync_app:latest
    entrypoint: ./dockerify/app/entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - '7050:7050'
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - .:/app/code
      - /tmp/apistatic:/tmp/apistatic
    networks:
      - app
      - logisy
    env_file:
      - secrets-stage.env

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
  logisy:
    external: true

volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
  pgbouncer:
  redis-data:
  redis-caddy-data1:

Description
If I try to run the project with the command below by modifying my entrypoint.sh then the server runs and also the logs and traces are being sent to SigNoz but after sometime it throws an error of Worker timeout as I am not using eventlet.
opentelemetry-instrument gunicorn shopify_sync.wsgi --workers=5 --log-level=info -b 0.0.0.0:7050 --reload
But if I try to run it with
opentelemetry-instrument gunicorn shopify_sync.wsgi --workers=5 --log-level=info -k eventlet -b 0.0.0.0:7050 --reload
It starts throwing many errors

8 RLock(s) were not greened, to fix this error make sure you run eventlet.monkey_patch() before importing any other modules.
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'read_replica1' was created in thread id 140260228932864 and this is thread id 140258667523840.

For the first issue I found out that monkey_patch() needs to be initalised before calling or importing any other modules, but even after doing it wsgi.py or manage.py or in entrypoint.sh this issue doesn't seem to go.
import eventlet; eventlet.monkey_patch()

For the second issue, I''ve multiple databases configured in the system, but why the error is happening here that I am not able to understand, this only comes if I try to run the project with opentelemetry-instument gunicorn eventlet or opentelemetry-instument gunicorn gevent
Snap 1

Snap 2

Please help me resolve these issues, Thank you!
